# Lie group compactness from generators

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, topology, poincare-symmetry

Let us consider the [Poincaré algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group#Poincar.C3.A9_algebra), characterized by the following commutators:
\begin{align}
[H,P_i]&=0\\
[H,K_i]&=P_i\\
[P_i,P_j]&=0\\
[K_i,K_j]&=-\epsilon_{ijk}J_k\\
[P_i,K_j]&=\delta_{ij}H\\
[J_i,J_j]&=\epsilon_{ijk}J_k\\
[J_i,K_j]&=\epsilon_{ijk}K_k\\
[J_i,P_j]&=\epsilon_{ijk}P_k\\
[J_i,H]&=0
\end{align}
How could I know - using the algebra only - if the subgroup, generated by the $K_i$ generators, is compact or not? Is there a criteria for establishing compactness?

My understanding of a compact group is related to the notion of bounded and connected sets. For example the Lorentz group has four disconnected pieces, so it's a non-compact group.

Comment: Computed the [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra)?

Comment: There is no subgroup generated by the K's, because their algebra doesn't "close".

Comment: Yes, its true. But the minimal subgroup, which contains this K as one of its generators?

Comment: I would recommend the following: Contrast the Killing form of SO(3), a sphere, to that of SO(2,1), a hyperboloid. Then, trash *H* and *P* to stick to the Lorentz algebra above, (after correcting your error in the [K,K]). Associate it to  SO(3,1), and observe the 5d hypersurface linked to the Killing form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Cosmas Zachos hints at in the comments, a non-Abelian Lie algebra belongs to a compact Lie group if its [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) $K(X;Y) = \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{ad}_X\circ \mathrm{ad}_Y)$ is negative-definite, cf. also [compact Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra) where you can find a full list of all compact Lie algebras. The reason for this is that a non-degenerate Killing form induces a Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_X Y = \frac{1}{2}[X,Y]$ on the Lie group with Ricci curvature $-\frac{1}{4}K(X,Y)$, which is bounded below if the Killing form is negative-definite and therefore the Lie group is compact by [Bonnet-Myers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem). Note that a negative-semidefinite Killing form, i.e. one which is degenerate, may or may not belong to a compact Lie group.

(Dis)connectedness has nothing to do with his - the Lorentz group is non-compact *and* has four connected components, but already the identity component, the proper orthochronous Lorentz group, is non-compact. Compactness and connectedness are different and unrelated topological properties.

Answer (score 5):

There is already a good answer by ACuriousMind. Here we want to stress some important facts.

1. Let there be given an $n$-dimensional real [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $$\mathfrak{g}~=~{\rm span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{t_a\mid a=1,\ldots, n\}, \tag{M1}$$
   where$^1$
   $$[t_a,t_b] ~=~\underbrace{f_{ab}{}^{c}}_{\in\mathbb{R}}~ t_c.\tag{M2}$$
2. Let us assume that the $t_a$'s are the generators of a faithful finite-dimensional linear representation of the Lie algebra, cf. [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem).
3. [Lie's third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%27s_third_theorem) (more precisely [Lie-Cartan's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie%27s+three+theorems)) guarantees the existence of a corresponding connected & simply-connected [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G$, such that its Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$. In a neighborhood of the identity, the Lie group is reconstructed by the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory))
   $$ \exp(\mathfrak{g})~\subseteq~ G \tag{M3}.$$
4. If the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra), the [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) is non-degenerate ([Cartan's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion)), and it has a [Cartan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition)
   $$\mathfrak{g}~=~\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}.\tag{M4}$$
   Then $K/Z_G$ is compact and $\exp(\mathfrak{p})$ non-compact, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition#Cartan_decomposition_on_the_Lie_group_level). We can construct a real semi-simple Lie algebra
   $$\mathfrak{g}_{\rm compact}~:=~\mathfrak{k}\oplus i\mathfrak{p}\tag{M5}$$
   with a negative definite Killing form. The corresponding connected & simply-connected Lie group $G_{\rm compact}$ is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), cf. Ref. 1.
5. Pure Lie group/algebra theory does not introduce a notion of [hermitian conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint). However, if $G_{\rm compact}\subseteq GL(V,\mathbb{C})$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, then we can use [Weyl's Unitarian_trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_trick) to construct a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) such that $G_{\rm compact}\subseteq U(V)$.
6. A sesquilinear form is often present in physics. If $t_a=-t^{\dagger}_a$ is anti-Hermitian, it corresponds to a compact direction; while if $t_a=t^{\dagger}_a$ is Hermitian, it corresponds to a non-compact direction.

References:

1. M.M. Alexandrino & R.G. Bettiol, *Introduction to Lie groups, isometric and adjoint actions and some generalizations,* [arXiv:0901.2374](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2374); Theorem 2.28.

--

$^1$ Be aware that in much of the physics literature, there is an extra factor of the imaginary unit $i$ in various places, e.g.
$$[t_a,t_b] ~=~i~\underbrace{f_{ab}{}^{c}}_{\in\mathbb{R}}~ t_c,\tag{P2}$$
and
$$ \exp(i\mathfrak{g})~\subseteq~ G \tag{P3}.$$
In particular, if $t_a=t^{\dagger}_a$ is Hermitian, it corresponds to a compact direction; while if $t_a=-t^{\dagger}_a$ is anti-Hermitian, it corresponds to a non-compact direction.

Comment: Notes for later: Math convention: $\quad GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ $[SL(n,\mathbb{R})]$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ compact and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}[-1]$ non-compact generators, respectively. $\quad SO^+(p,q;\mathbb{R})$ has $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$ compact and $pq$ non-compact generators. $\quad Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b_S \cr c_S & -a^T\end{pmatrix} \right\}$ has $n^2$ compact and $n(n+1)$ non-compact generators. RaS=aH=C. RS=H=nC. A Lie group whose Lie algebra is a complex vectors space has an equal number of compact and non-compact generators.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad U(p,q)$ [$SU(p,q)$] has $p^2+q^2[-1]$ compact and $2pq$ non-compact generators, respectively. $\quad Sp(p,q)$ has $p(2p+1)+q(2q+1)$ compact and $4pq$ non-compact generators. aH=C. H=nC. Cartan involution: $\quad\theta(x)=-x^t$. $\quad\theta([x,y])=[\theta(x),\theta(y)]$. The invariant bilinear form $\quad \beta(x,y)={\rm tr}(xy)$ has positive (negative) signature for Hermitian (anti-Hermitian) elements, respectively.