# About the notation of Lie algebra, upstairs and downstairs indices

Tags: group-theory, notation, lie-algebra

In some textbooks, Lie algebra is written as $$[X_a, X_b]=if_{abc}X_c$$ where $X_a$'s are the generators of the Lie group. But sometimes, the Lie algebra is written as $$[X_a,X_b]=if_{ab}^{~~~ c}X_c$$ or sometimes as
$$[X^a, X^b]=if^{ab}_{~~~ c}X^c$$ where the index $c$ on the right-hand side of each expression is assumed to be summed over and $f$'s stand for structure constants.

Why are indices sometimes written as upstairs and sometimes as downstairs and sometimes everything downstairs? Is there a tool for raising or lowering indices?

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, the [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) yields a natural notion of a [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) for a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra). It is non-degenerate if the Lie algebra is [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra).
2. For [compact semisimple Lie algebras](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364185/2451) many physicists use a choice of basis where the components of the metric tensor is the identity matrix, so that there are no difference between upper and lower Lie algebra indices.