# Time dependent Hamiltonian operator and $SU(1,1)$ generator method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, hamiltonian, lie-algebra

In this screenshot of a paper I am reading, I have the following question:

1.What is a $SU(1,1)$ group and how do we find its generators?

2.From the expression for the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, how do we infer the form of the operator $\hat{U}(t,0)$ as in the equation $6$?

3.How can I write a similar definition of $\hat{U}$ for time $t_0$ to $t$ rather than $0$ to $t$?

P.S. Any resource recommendation would be appreciated. 
[image: .]

Comment: From which paper? Link?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183414/2451 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59717/11127

Comment: @Qmechanic Title: "Squeezing by tuning the oscillator frequency" by C F Lo